# indefinite article + possessive constructions?

Tags: articles

Is this proper Italian:

> *Un nostro amico*

To mean what one would say in English: "A friend of ours"?

Or

> *Alcuni nostri amici*

to mean "some friends of ours"?

Comment: “Un nostro amico” and “alcuni nostri amici” are proper Italian! What’s your issue?